# Display time x on webpage after adding 24 hours to a specifc time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `JQuery` to make a countdown that updates itself automatically after 24 hours from a specific time of day.I just want to know how to display time **x**
by taking an a certain hour of the day and adding  24 hours to it to make time **y**, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get time in milliseconds, increment it by a number of seconds in a day

```
var y = new Date(x.getTime()+1000*60*60*24);
```

Comment: Thanks...that helped